# «Сегодня День защиты детей». Тире не нужно?

Tags: пунктуация

«Сегодня День защиты детей». Тире не нужно в предложении?

Comment: Вы не читаете комментарии?

Answer (score 3):

Неполное двусоставное предложение, в котором обстоятельство СЕГОДНЯ относится к отсутствующему, но предполагаемому глаголу-сказуемому ЕСТЬ. На его месте при большом желании можно поставить ТИРЕ (если хотите подчеркнуть паузу), но без тире предложение выглядит лучше. Ср.: *Завтра экзамен.*

Comment: Сегодня есть День защиты детей? Это ж на каковском языке? Если предполагать, то — Отмечается, Празднуется.

Answer (score 2):

Тире не нужно.

*Сегодня* (и *вчера*, на случай) не является Днём защиты детей. На этот день приходится празднование.

1 июня — День защиты детей.

Answer (score 2):

Тире желательно, если фраза содержит смысловое ударение на вторую часть. Обычно так и есть, с восклицательным знаком тире точно нужно.

Comment: Ну, положим, не точно, но в общем-то да, восклицательное предложение  с тире смотрится лучще.

Answer (score 1):

Тире не требуется, но возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Для одного изолированного предложения **сложно дать правильную оценку** (лучше звучит или хуже звучит), постановка тире здесь зависит **от контекста**, например:

Ведущий: Всем, всем – добрый день! Всем лучезарных улыбок и хорошего настроения! **Сегодня действительно добрый день, потому что сегОдня – день защиты детЕй!**

Слово "сегодня" желательно выделить тире и паузой, тогда и постановка восклицательного знака будет оправданной, так как именно название праздника (а не целое предложение) удобно произнести **с восклицательной интонацией**.